# Linq to Sql any keyword search query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a case in my application where the user can search for a list of terms. The search needs to make three passes in the following order:

- One for an exact match of what they entered. Done, easy.
- One where all the words (individually) match. Done, also easy.
- One where *any* of the words match...how?

Essentially, how do I, in Linq to Sql, tell it to do this:

```
select * from stuff s where s.Title like '%blah%' || s.Title like '%woo&' || s.Title like '%fghwgads%' || s.Title like...
```

And so on?

Comment: You should know that this kind of thing is really best handled by Full-Text Search.  The `LIKE '%xyz%'` version will run, but the performance will suck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a tough one... I think you'd have to write your own operator.

(**Update:** Yep, I tested it, it works.)

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> LikeAny<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> selector,
        IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        }
        if (values == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
        }
        if (!values.Any())
        {
            return query;
        }
        var p = selector.Parameters.Single();
        var conditions = values.Select(v =>
            (Expression)Expression.Call(typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null,
                selector.Body, Expression.Constant("%" + v + "%")));
        var body = conditions.Aggregate((acc, c) => Expression.Or(acc, c));
        return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, p));
    }
}
```

Then you could call this with:

```
string[] terms = new string[] { "blah", "woo", "fghwgads" };
var results = stuff.LikeAny(s => s.Title, terms);
```

P.S. You'll need to add the `System.Linq.Expressions` and `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` namespaces to your namespaces for the `QueryExtensions` class.

Comment: I used the code in Linq to Entities, and I get this error:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.