# Translating this query in LINQ ? (list of like)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to translate this query in LINQ ... it is very easy to construct if we do it in pure SQL but in dynamically created LINQ query (building a search query based on user input) it's a whole new story.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE 1=1
  AND Column2 IN (1,2,3)
  AND ( Column1 LIKE '%a%' OR Column1 LIKE '%b%' )
```

Now to try to construct this we tried it this way :

```
if(myOjb.Column2Collection != null)
    query = query.where(f => f.Column2.Contains(myOjb.Column2Collection));

if(myObj.Column1Collection != null)
{
    // tough part here ?
    //query = query.Where(); ...
}
```

So what would be the best aproach to this normally ?

Note that I am aware of the SqlMethod.Like, tho I can't figure a way to implement it here ...

Comment: What is the purpose of `WHERE 1=1`? Won't that just mean `True` and won't make a difference?

Comment: @G_M - normally this is done when constructing dynamic SQL so you don't need to keep checking for an existing where clause.

Comment: Is your question how to handle an OR dynamically?

Comment: I think your question is just a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647130/building-up-a-query-expression-dynamically-or

Answer (score 1):

To get the Like.. Or Like.. etc, I think you have to write your own extension to build the expression tree for you.  I wanted to do this a while ago and ended up finding a different article here on StackOverflow: [Linq to Sql any keyword search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010639/linq-to-sql-any-keyword-search-query)

From there, I think you would write this:

```
string[] terms = new string[] {"a", "b"}
query = query.LikeAny(table => table.Column1, terms)
```

BTW, you can also change the code on the linked page to do AND rather than OR by changing

```
var body = conditions.Aggregate((acc, c) => Expression.Or(acc, c));
```

to

```
var body = conditions.Aggregate((acc, c) => Expression.And(acc, c));
```

which was what I wanted at the time, calling it LikeAll

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var colums2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = (from o in myOjb
              where columns2.Any(co2 => co2 == o.Column2)
              && Column1.Contains(column2valueA)
              || Column1.Contains(column2valueB)
              select o);
```

Hope can help

Comment: Oh... sorry. i edit post (i suppose that we have only two filters?)

Comment: Never use `ToLower()`, use `StringComparison` instead

Comment: This will cause a case-sensitive comparison, and your first line will also cause a compiler error since the type of `columns2` can't be unambiguously inferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sc = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var col2Values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };    

var query = from item in myObj
            where col2Values.Contains(item.Column2)
            && (item.Column1.IndexOf("a", sc) >= 0
                || item.Column1.IndexOf("b", sc) >= 0)
            select item;
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it builds just fine. Original version if the above fails:

```
var col2Values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var query = from item in myObj
            let col1 = item.Column1.ToLower()
            where col2Values.Contains(item.Column2)
            && (col1.Contains("a") || col1.Contains("b"))
            select item;
```

I actually prefer the second version, even if it is *slightly* slower because of the `ToLower()`. To my eye, it's easier to read. YMMV.

Comment: Never use `ToLower()`, use `StringComparison` instead

Comment: @abatishchev: `StringComparison` was what I was trying to remember. I'll edit.

Comment: Wouldn't work on a dynamically created query, and it does not work with the % operator SqlMethods.Like() is the way to work with it, but I can't see a way to make it work here.

Comment: @Erick: What exactly wouldn't work? You mean the `string.Contains` version or the `string.IndexOf` version? I believe `string.Contains` works in .NET 4.0, but I can't remember whether I used it in LINQtoObjects or LINQtoEntities, so I don't know if it can get converted into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
from o in myObj
where
new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(o.Column2) &&
new[] { "a", "b" }.Any(s => o.Column1.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1)
select o;
```

---

or use `new Hashset<T>` if you care about lookup performance. Array brings only O(n).

---

`Ordinal` means unicode comparison byte-per-byte without culture-specific issues, the most quick.

`OrdinalIgnoreCase` means the same but case-sensitively

Comment: Problem here, it does not work with the % operator like SqlMethod.Like does, and also can't work with a list of parenthesis also... (the (where1 or where2) )

Comment: @Erick: I edited a bit to correspond with your query exactly.

Comment: This won't compile. `string.Contains` can't take `StringComparer.Ordinal` as a parameter, and you're missing a ( and a } on the fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647130/building-up-a-query-expression-dynamically-or).